# Fatal exception AsyncTask #1 android Watson translator

Tags: java, ibm-watson, android-studio-3.0

I keep getting the following exception when I Click on the translate button in my application:
I have made sure that my watson APi key is correct..

I am using the watson Translator Api only to translate specific phrases from my database...
All the database methods work fine I just seem to have an error in the Translation Task.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.translatorapp1, PID: 18199
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while fetching access token from token service: 
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.getToken(TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.java:252)
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.java:194)
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.BaseService.setAuthentication(BaseService.java:260)
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.BaseService.createCall(BaseService.java:198)
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.BaseService.createServiceCall(BaseService.java:236)
        at com.ibm.watson.language_translator.v3.LanguageTranslator.translate(LanguageTranslator.java:152)
        at com.example.translatorapp1.PhraseTranslator$TranslationTask.doInBackground(PhraseTranslator.java:132)
        at com.example.translatorapp1.PhraseTranslator$TranslationTask.doInBackground(PhraseTranslator.java:123)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
        at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:244)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator$2.run(TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.java:307)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

This is my TranslatorClass

```
public class PhraseTranslator extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LanguageTranslator translationService;

    DatabaseConn langDb;

    TextView displayTrans;
    Spinner  languagesSpinner;
    ListView phrasesLv;
    Button   translateBtn;

    ArrayList<String> p;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerLang;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;

    String selectedPhrase;

    private String selectedTargetLanguage = "es";

    //private StreamPlayer player = new StreamPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phrase_translator);

        displayTrans       = findViewById(R.id.displayTransTextView);
        languagesSpinner   = findViewById(R.id.possibleLangspinner);
        phrasesLv          = findViewById(R.id.displayWordsListView);
        translateBtn       = findViewById(R.id.translateBtn);



        //database connection.
        langDb = new DatabaseConn(this);

        //allow only one choice at a time
        phrasesLv.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        p           = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerLang = new ArrayList<>();


        adapter         = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PhraseTranslator.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, p);
        spinnerAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PhraseTranslator.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerLang);

        //retrives subscribed languages and adds them to array.
        getSubscribedLang(spinnerLang);

        translateBtn.setEnabled(false);

        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //adds subscribed languages to the spinner
        translationService = initLanguageTranslatorService();

        langDb.display(p);

        Collections.sort(p);


        phrasesLv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedPhrase = phrasesLv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                translateBtn.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });

        phrasesLv.setAdapter(adapter);
        languagesSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        //when translate Button is pressed
        translateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new TranslationTask().execute(selectedPhrase);


            }
        });



    }

    private LanguageTranslator initLanguageTranslatorService() {
        Authenticator authenticator
                = new IamAuthenticator(getString(R.string.visual_recognition_iam_apikey));
        LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator("2018-05-01", authenticator);
        service.setServiceUrl(getString(R.string.visual_recognition_url));
        return service;
    }

    private class TranslationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            TranslateOptions translateOptions = new TranslateOptions.Builder()
                    .addText(params[0])
                    .source(Language.ENGLISH)
                    .target(Language.SPANISH)
                    .build();
            TranslationResult result = translationService.translate(translateOptions).execute().getResult();
            String firstTranslation = result.getTranslations().get(0).getTranslation();
            return firstTranslation;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            displayTrans.setText(s);
        }
    }
//retrives the subscribed languages from the database

    public void getSubscribedLang(ArrayList<String> a){
        langDb.rertrivesubscriptions(a);


    }


}
```

This is my layout Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PhraseTranslator">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/displayWordsListView"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="424dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/translateBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/possibleLangspinner"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/displayWordsListView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/translateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/translate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayTransTextView"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/possibleLangspinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick check shows that you refer to Visual Recognition for both the authentication and service URL. Not sure if that's the issue here, but the API keys and URLs are service-specific unless you're sharing information between services.

Check the details in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator/language-translator?code=java#authentication) if you haven't already

Comment: Hello Allen, I've already checked that, for some reason it seems to run fine on another computer but not on mine? would you know why that would happen ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem Wrong with My android Studio version Which Caused this error.